# Report Header text are wrapped

Tags: phpexcel

I am using PHPExcel and found it to be an excellent tool for rendering reports on PHP platform.

I am trying to set a header text on my page - but the issue is that it gets wrapped on on the same column though I am not writing further on that column:

```
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel(); 
            $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0); 
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->insertNewRowBefore(1, 2);
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1')->getAlignment()->setWrapText(false);
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A1', 'Amrit Transactions Details for the Month');
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1')->getFont()->setBold(true);
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1')->getBorders()->getTop()->setBorderStyle(PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_THIN);
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1')->getFont()->getColor()->setARGB(PHPExcel_Style_Color::COLOR_RED);
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1')->getFont()->setSize(18);
```

[image]

How can I fix it?

Comment: Perhaps try merging cells `A1:H1`

Comment: @MarkBaker Thanks  - it helped - but one small clarification I need to make - how can I display excel charts / graph in browser?

Comment: Really should have been asked as a separate question, but take a look at how `35chartrender.php` in `/Examples` creates an image file from a chart, and use that process.... you can also simply try using `setIncludeCharts(TRUE)` if you're using the HTML Writer